# Percent values in graphite stacked graph

Tags: graph, monitoring, graphite

I have a Graphite graph that integrates some values, and stack them. To doing so, i used this query:

```
stacked(integral(groupByNode(counters.*.*.crawler_count:sum, 2, "sumSeries")))
```

So, doing this i have a monotonic function as a result. What i would like to do is to have the stack to be resized to have always the same y value, so i can tell the proportion of each stacked value.

Like this graph:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

I've used the divideSeries function with itself, so the values always sum up to one:

```
stacked(divideSeries(integral(groupByNode(counters.jusbrasil.*.*.saved_success:sum, 2, "sumSeries")), integral(sum(counters.jusbrasil.*.*.saved_success:sum))))
```